# Why is docker pushing old code to remote server

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr

I've tried pushing the newly built image to ECR but it seemed that it always kept pushing the old code from cache to ECR. I've tried to clear out cache with the following commands and rebuilt the image but the issue remained:

- Clear out docker

```
docker rmi $$(docker images | grep none | awk '{print $$3}') -f
docker system prune -a -f
```

- Rebuild the image

```
docker build -t $(DOMAIN)/$(REPO_NAME):$(IMAGE_VERSION) -f docker/Dockerfile . --no-cache
```

- pushing the image to ECR

```
docker push $REPO_ID.dkr.ecr.$REGION.amazonaws.com/$(DOMAIN)/$(REPO_NAME):$(IMAGE_VERSION)
```

I've tested the built image locally and it works with the new code. However, when I run the image remotely, it ran the old code and failed

I have no idea what was going on. Can someone help me on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have sorted this out. I would need to update the function image by the following:

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my-lambda-func --image-uri $REPO_ID.dkr.ecr.$REGION.amazonaws.com/$(DOMAIN)/$(REPO_NAME):latest
```

Comment: BTW, feel free to accept your own answer if you want…

Answer (score 1):

You don't explicitly say where/how you are running that image "remotely". Could it be that you are re-using tags and those images are cached on the "remote" nodes you are deploying to (e.g. EKS cluster or ECS/EC2 cluster)? In that case, depending on the host configuration/state it may not even reach to ECR to pull the new image if the node (thinks to have) found the same image cached.

[Update] Following up from the comments, the problem occurs in a Lambda function and [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/working-with-lambda-layers-and-extensions-in-container-images/) has hints about how to update the code in the Lambda.

Comment: In terms of where/how I run the image, it was a lambda function wrapped in a docker image hosted on ECR. I would just call that lambda function from inside the docker image as follows:

`aws --profile $MY_AWS_PROFILE \
  lambda \
  invoke \
  --function-name $LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME \
  --payload '{"body": {"x": 5.9, "y": 3}}' \
`

Comment: I see. There are many variables at play here without knowing the whole context and see all the system moving. E.g. are you using the same tag (`IMAGE_VERSION`) when you push etc. I would personally try/experimenting using different tags and/or deleting images on ECR before you push them (if you use the same tag) or anything that would try to narrow the part of the end-to-end process that breaks your expected outcome.

Comment: In addition, consider that Lambda may be caching your images according to [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/working-with-lambda-layers-and-extensions-in-container-images/) ("Lambda also optimizes the image and caches it close to where the functions runs so cold start times are the same as for .zip archives"). [This re:Invent session](https://virtual.awsevents.com/media/1_gu6tp8sd) may have more details.

Comment: Indeed; also it seems the [blog article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/working-with-lambda-layers-and-extensions-in-container-images/) you mentioned directly contains the command mentioned in @AnNguyen's answer: "If […] the function code changes, you need to update the function image […] `aws lambda update-function-code …`" (and you might want to directly cite this hyperlink in your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, the issue is that there is a **mismatch** in the name (a.k.a. tag) of the two images:

```
docker build -t $(DOMAIN)/$(REPO_NAME):$(IMAGE_VERSION) -f docker/Dockerfile . --no-cache

docker push $REPO_ID.dkr.ecr.$REGION.amazonaws.com/$(DOMAIN)/$(REPO_NAME):$(IMAGE_VERSION)
```

so you should probably write:

```
docker build -t $REPO_ID.dkr.ecr.$REGION.amazonaws.com/$(DOMAIN)/$(REPO_NAME):$(IMAGE_VERSION) -f docker/Dockerfile . --no-cache
```

instead.

Comment: I've not been clear in the command, I tagged the built image before pushing it to ECR using that tag. This is the command before I do the pushing: 

``` 
docker tag $(DOMAIN)/$(REPO_NAME):$(IMAGE_VERSION) $REPO_ID.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/$(DOMAIN)/$(REPO_NAME):$(IMAGE_VERSION)
```

Comment: OK I see. But anyway, running both `docker build -t bar . && docker tag bar foo/bar` looks unnecessary, as you could directly run `docker build -t foo/bar .` (but admittedly, this is not the cause of your issue).